# Travelling Salesman Problem - where's the "return to city"-constraint?

Tags: algorithms

I'm looking at your standard definition of the TSP.... (see wikipedia).... and in the statement leading up to the definition, it states that we must return to the city we began from.

Which constraint makes sure that this is the case?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Integer_linear_programming_formulation

Answer (score 1):

The constraint 
$\sum_{i=1,i \neq j}^n x_{ij}=1$ makes sure that for every city there is a next city and the constraint $\sum_{j=1,j \neq i}^n x_{ij}=1$ guarantee that for each city there exists a previous one. So necessarely there is a "return to the city".